# minWidth and minHeight has no effect on ImageView (Android)

Tags: java, android, imageview, adjustviewbounds

For whatever reason, setting the minHeight and maxHeight has no effect on the image dimension inside an ImageView component.  In some cases, I end up with a VERY SMALL image. I presume this is due to the fact that I have the width and height set to "wrap_content" and "adjustViewBounds" set to true.

If I set "adjustViewBounds" to false, the image does expand to whatever I specify for minWidth and/or minHeight.  However, in this case the image becomes distorted because its width and height are not scaled in proportion. I would like to avoid this situation too.

I end up writing a big chunk of code (as follows) to overwrite the onMeasure() method of ImageView.  Is this really necessary?

```
public class FlexibleImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "FlexibleImageView";

    public FlexibleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            boolean adjustViewBounds = getAdjustViewBounds();
            int minWidth = Math.max(getMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumWidth());
            int minHeight = Math.max(getMinimumHeight(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
            int maxWidth = getMaxWidth();
            int maxHeight = getMaxHeight();
            int widthSpec = getMeasuredWidth();
            int heightSpec = getMeasuredHeight();

            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            if (d != null && adjustViewBounds) {

                // Scale UP if the size is too small
                float scale, scaleW = 1.0f, scaleH = 1.0f;
                if (widthSpec < minWidth)
                    scaleW = (float) minWidth / (float) widthSpec;
                if (heightSpec < minHeight)
                    scaleH = (float) minHeight / (float) heightSpec;
                scale = (scaleW > scaleH) ? scaleW : scaleH;

                if (scale > 1.0) {

                    int targetW = (int) Math.ceil(widthSpec * scale);
                    int targetH = (int) Math.ceil(heightSpec * scale);

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Measured dimension (" + widthSpec + "x" + heightSpec
                            + ") too small.  Resizing to " + targetW + "x" + targetH);

                    // Make sure targetW, targetH stays within the bounds of maxW, maxH
                    if(targetW > maxWidth) {
                        targetH = targetH * maxWidth / targetW;
                        targetW = maxWidth;

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Capping width to " + maxWidth);
                    }
                    if(targetH > maxHeight) {
                        targetW = targetW * maxHeight / targetH;
                        targetH = maxHeight;

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Capping height to " + maxHeight);
                    }
                    setMeasuredDimension(targetW, targetH);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And XML portion:

```
<cards.myb.ui.FlexibleImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageCard"
    android:contentDescription="@string/card_image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/card_editor_img_min_dimen"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/fb_logo" />
```

Comment: There's some difference in `android:src` and `android:background `.. The above problem might get solved by setting as background.. I had one similar condition.. Never really understood why ..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I have tried using android:background instead.  At the same time, I set adjustViewBounds to false.  Yes -- the image gets stretched to minWidth and/or minHeight.    Unfortunately, the aspect ratio of the ImageView is no longer dependent on the "background" image.

Comment: Please do tag my name if found a good solution, Thanks :)

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do so (tag).  Perhaps I am still too new to this community?